# jQuery add/remove required class for validation before form submission

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form with many fields in which two of these fields are *sort of* mutually exclusive, i.e. if one is empty the other **must** be present and the opposite is true (but they **can** be present at the same time). I have a simple validation check before submission which scans all fields with `class="required"` (no plugin), so i implemented the following code to perform validation of **one field or the other**:

```
$('#field1').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $('#field2').removeClass('required');
    $(this).addClass('required');
  }      
});

$('#field2').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).addClass('required');
    $('#field1').removeClass('required');
  }
});
```

where `#field1` and `#field2` are the two mutually exclusive fields.

I've checked with Firebug and the classes are correctly added/removed.

**The problem is**:

if I trigger one or the other field, my form gets submitted **even if other required fields are left blank**.

Validation code is:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
var fields = $('.validate');
var ret_value = true;
$.each(fields, function(){
  if ($(this).find('.required').val().length < 1) {
    $(this).find('.errors').html('Campo obbligatorio!');
    ret_value = false;        
  }      
});
return ret_value;
```

});

where a required input field's html is:

```
<span class="validate">
   <label for="field">Required Field</label>
   <input name="field" id="field" class="required">
   <span class="errors"></span>
</span>
```

Form validation performs correctly if I don't add/remove the `required` class with the code above.

If i set a breakpoint in Firebug where I set

```
ret_value = false;
```

code gets executed, but for some reason it never gets to

```
return ret_value;
```

Also, inspecting the `fields` variable in Firebug I can see the correct entries.

As I stated before, if I **don't modify** `#field1` and `#field2`, everything works correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: in your html, #field1 and #field2 has the required class?

Comment: @Guilherme Serrano, #field1 starts as "required", not #field2. But it doesn't matter, if they don't get modified by my script it works... I think @Detect is correct btw, i'm testing it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it can fail on this conditional:

```
if ($(this).find('.required').val().length < 1)
```

if it cannot find any elements with the required class, then.val() returns undefined on [] and .length on undefined is borked.

One way to solve this is to change the fields to only check the child elements of the validate class with the required class.

So you would change:

```
var fields = $('.validate');
```

to:

```
var fields = $('.validate > .required');
```

and...

```
$.each(fields, function(){
  if ($(this).find('.required').val().length < 1) {
    $(this).find('.errors').html('Campo obbligatorio!');
    ret_value = false;        
  }      
});
```

to:

```
$.each(fields, function(){
  if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
    $(this).siblings('.errors').html('Campo obbligatorio!');
    ret_value = false;        
  }      
});
```

Comment: That was it! Works like a charm now.